# do block with flower brackets in ghci throws error

Tags: haskell, monads

I have a code that works with print inside do block as,

```
do { print ([(n, 2^n) | n <- [0..19]]) }
```

Then i tried a much simpler version to print a variable value,

```
do { let a = 1; print (a) }
```

It throws error as `parse error on input }`

What else, i tried with no success ---

```
ghci> let a = 1; print (a)
```

And

```
ghci> :{
    |  let a = 1;
    |  print (a)
    |  :}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you start a `let` statement, the rest of the line is considered to be additional `let` assignments. Consider this error message:

```
ghci> do print 1; let c = 2; d = 3
<interactive>:3:13:
    The last statement in a 'do' block must be an expression
      let c = 2
          d = 3
```

Note that the `let` keyword is not needed for `d = 3`.

To add a monadic statement after a `let` you'll need to put it on a separate line (with the correct indentation):

```
ghci> :{
    | do print 1; let a = 2; b = 3
    |    print b
    | :}
1
3
```

AFAIK, there is no way to put a monadic statement after a `let` on the same line.

Comment: You can put it on the same line simply by adding brackets to the `let` as well: `do { let { a = 1 }; print a }`.

Comment: @DanielWagner Yep. *everything* in Haskell which requires line breaks or indentation can be considered syntactic sugar for appropriately placed `{ ; }` characters. (*Brace for counterexample*)